# Translate JMeter menu items

Tags: localization, jmeter, translation

About Translate JMeter projects,

I follow the [translating](http://jmeter.apache.org/localising/index.html#translating) steps and open I18NEdit,

I see the translation text options but I notice that I can't localize Menu items as File, Exit,..

It seems that there are texts (messages.properties) that can't be localized.

Is messages.properties localization is done manually by adding  messages_[locale].properties?

Am I missing something ? Is it on purpose or should an enhancement be opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't really use i18nedit for translation. But you can still use it.

Anyway, Internationalization in JMeter is based on properties files:

- src/core/org/apache/jmeter/resources/messages_[locale].properties
- src/components/..../*.properties (except some like colors.properties)
- src/protocol/..../*.properties

No need to translate deprecated components.

The 2 latter are related to components that rely on TestBean approach (no specific GUI)

Note that a PR (github mirror) is preferred over a patch:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: I was asking about contribution of new language. Menu items aren't avialable in I18NEdit